Algorithm to determine stabilizer subgroup of a hermitian matrix in $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$
Consider the group of $n \times n$ matrices $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$. Let $H$ be a Hermitian $n \times n$ matrix. The stabilizer subgroup of $H$ with respect to the conjugate group action is
$$S_H := \{g \in GL_n(\mathbb{C}) : gHg^{-1} = H\}.$$
Is there an algorithm (or systematic method) to determine $S_H$? Special cases would still be helpful.

Hint: First, diagonalize $H$.

@MoisheKohan Hm, so that an equivalent condition is $V^{-1}gV D V^{-1}g^{-1}V = D$? Then, I suppose this can be abstracted to $gDg^{-1} = D$, which is a simpler condition. Am I taking your hint in the right direction?

Of course. Do you know how to proceed from there?

@MoisheKohan I have got to sleep now, but I will think on it. Thank you for the first hint!

@MoisheKohan Naively, I can obtain a system of $n \times n$ equations of the form $g_{ij}D_{jk}(g^{-1}){kl} = \lambda{il}\delta_{il}$, but I am not sure if this is the smartest way to proceed as its solvability does not scale as $n$ gets large.

Oh, no, this is not a way to proceed. What can you say about eigenspaces under conjugation?

@MoisheKohan I believe can say that if $\lambda \sum_i v^T_i v_i$ is an eigenspace (sum allowing for possible degeneracy), then conjugation needs to send it into an eigenspace of same dimension as the conjugate action is invertible.
